# Why do I have python39.dll file missing after the installation of python 3.9.1amd64?

Tags: python, windows, system-error

I am python new user,but after a successful installation. After execution, I have the following message:

`The code execution cannot proceed because python39.dll was not found.Reinstalling he programm may fix this problem`

I have tried to download 'python.dll'from wikidll.com , it is a winrar folder. After extracting the files and place them first of all in the windows system and secondly in the python installation file, I have the same problem.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The downloaded dll wont work because it's the wrong dll file. The missing file is python39.dll but you have downloaded python.dll which is not the same.

You need Win 8 or later to install Python 3.9.1. I hope your system has it. If you don't have then I suggest you download a compatible version.

You can find the missing dll file in the link below :
https://mega.nz/file/M2o2ARqR#tZIEd4CFIkp_MkrfNy7GbBeSl4c7P0CG3XkwpXBIJ64

If this doesn't solve the issue then I suggest you to re install python! Hope it helps.

Comment: Downvoted for the reference to download a DLL file from an insecure location.

Answer (score 3):

I would not advise the downloading of dlls/exes from untrusted websites as you never know if there is any "additional payload"/malware provided with it.

Check out the latest 3.9.4 Python for Windows at
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-394

I just installed it on my machine and python39.dll was there :)

I didn't test the 3.9.1 installer, but if the dll is missing then it is in the "embeddable package", which can find at

https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391